# cog / replicate build artifacts missing

Tags: python-3.x, docker, replicate

Im using cog / replicate to deploy a model.
In my cog.yaml I do the following:

```
run:
      - "git clone https://github.com/152334H/tortoise-tts-fast"
      - "cd tortoise-tts-fast"
      - "cd tortoise-tts-fast && pip install -e ."
```

This appears to install correctly but the directory tortoise-tts-fast is gone in the built image, does anyone know how im supposed to install this so that i can access it in the built image?

Thanks